# sailsjs logging - fail to print argument values

Tags: sails.js, winston

I am using Sails v0.10, the logger is based on Winston, but while logging I fail to print string arguments.

**Problem**

```
var name = 'sails';
var email = 'x@y.com';
sails.log.verbose('name=%s, email=%s, password=%s', name, email);
//Output: name=%s, email=%ssails x@y.com
//Expected: name=sails, email=x@y.com
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The default Sails logger ([captains-log](https://github.com/balderdashy/captains-log)) no longer wraps Winston.  I've updated the docs to reflect the change (thanks for pointing it out!)

The syntax for your example would be:

```
sails.log.verbose("name=",name,"email=",email)
```

more like regular `console.log` syntax.  See the [readme](https://github.com/balderdashy/captains-log) for Captain's Log to see an example of how to use it with Winston, if that's what you prefer.